# Why is g is less than p in Diffie-Hellman?

Tags: diffie-hellman

In non-authenticated DH, p and g are made as public record. p needs to be a large prime number and g should be smaller than p.  Why does g need to be smaller than p?

Answer (score 5):

It's an element of the field of all integers modulo $p$, and these are represented by the numbers $0,\ldots, p-1$. And $g$ will be one of them.

Comment: I am asking why does g need to be small? Why can not we have g greater than p?

Comment: If $g > p$, then it is the same as if we had chosen $g \mod p$, which is $< p$. We are doing all operations modulo $p$. E.g. modulo $p=7$, it's the same whether we choose $g=2$ or $g=9$ or $g=16$ etc.